# Can't access localhost from a web server on my local network

Tags: php, mysql, windows, server, xampp

This question will look like an essay because it is really weird (at least I can't see the logic on the problem.

I am running two computers right now, one Toshiba NB510 which I want to use as a web server, with XAMPP and controlled with VNC from my second (and main) computer, an MSI 2qe (with also XAMPP installed).

The problem is that when I run Apache and MySQL from the MSI, I can write to my local IP to access from any device on my LAN to access "localhost" (until this all ok) but when I run XAMPP on the web server I can only access to localhost from that computer (using the local IP).

Maybe it's a problem on my network?

Here is a map of the network (done in paint sorry)

[image]

Comment: XAMPP like any web server comes with a default config that ONLY allows access from the PC that it is installed on. Security! So find the Apache config file and change the `Require local` to something like `Require ip 192.168.1` and ANY pc in your network will be able to access the web server using `192.168.1.35`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think that was the problem but i messed up... :,) Now I'm uninstalling and reinstalling xampp, I'm going to copy all the files from the msi to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You have two pcs. Both with your servers running, but you can't access one of them correct ?

The usual troubleshooting for this is :

- first to check if you can ping it (to make sure it's on the network)
- second to check if the ports you will use are open (tipically, 80 for
  web)
- finally to check if your server is set to accept incoming connection
  (Apache config)

EDIT:

I've seen your picture now. If as you said, both PCs can "see" each other (as in, Toshiba can ping and access MSI, and MSI can ping toshiba but not access it) check if your commumator is the source of the problem

Comment: Well actually no, the problem is on the toshiba, i can acess the web server from it but not from the msi. the web server of the msi was only bc i dont know why it works on it but not on the toshiba. i can ping it and ports are open, and the apache config is the same as in the msi

Comment: When i arrive home i will try to avoid coneccting the toshiba to the commuter. I'll keep you informed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All solved, I installed windows 10 x64 instead of x32 and reinstalled xampp and all works